# Delete Individual Sessions in PHP

Tags: php, session

I've been going at this for hours.
I have a website and a blog.

I register the blog sessions with the code below;

```
    session_id("blog");
    session_start();
    $_SESSION["blog"]["username"] = $_POST['username'];
    $_SESSION["blog"]["password"] = $_POST['password'];
    $_SESSION["blog"]["firstName"] = $row ['user_firstname'];
    $_SESSION["blog"]["lastName"] = $row ['user_lastname'];
```

I register the website session with the code below;

```
    session_id("web");
    session_start();
    $_SESSION["web"]["email"] = $_POST['email'];
    $_SESSION["web"]["password"] = $_POST['password'];
    $_SESSION["web"]["firstName"] = $row ['firstName'];
    $_SESSION["web"]["lastName"] = $row ['lastName'];
```

I logout individual sessions with the code below;

```
    session_id("web");
    session_start();
    session_destroy();
```

And

```
    session_id("blog");
    session_start();
    session_destroy();
```

This is not working as logs out the website because only one PHPSESSID is created when I check in chrome.

- How do I create multiple sessions
- How do I assign variables to them
- How do I log them out independently

Thanks :)

Comment: You can ignore session_id. When you want to destroy the web session, instead of session_destroy, just unset($_SESSION['web']);. Similarly,  you can unset($_SESSION['blog']);

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply use the [unset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php) method.

```
 // Lets start php sessions. This must go before any other headers
session_start();

// When setting
$_SESSION['web'] = array( 
                            "email" => "email@email.com",
                            "password" => "password",
                            "firstname" => "Jonas",
                            "lastname" => "M" 
                        );


// When unsetting
unset( $_SESSION['web'] );

// OR you can null it

$_SESSION['web'] = null;
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I'm just testing it at the moment.
How do I get the elements in the array to use in a query?

Comment: what do you mean by "Using in a query?"  To output the content of a session, you just say  $_SESSION['web']['email']   - Etc: echo  $_SESSION['web']['email'];

Comment: The query below is not working;
`"SELECT * FROM qwickgrub_users WHERE email = $_SESSION['web']['email']";`

Comment: Sorted now. Thanks!
Marking as answer!

Answer (score 1):

```
//start session - have to be only once 
session_start();

//create session variable - in your word create individual session and assign variable 
$_SESSION['session_name'] = "name";
$_SESSION["session_name"]["variable1"] = $variable1_value;
$_SESSION["session_name"]["variable2"] = $variable2_value;

//unset individual session variable - in your word logout individual session
unset($_SESSION['session_name']);
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I'm just testing it at the moment. How do I get the elements in the array to use in a query?

Comment: just use $_SESSION["session_name"]["variable"]